# Subversion Website

Tags: apache, svn, centos

so i have a virtualmin on a centos 6.7 and what one of the devs asked me to do got me thinking. as i know all files of a Subversion repository are stored in a DB and not in a folder... so i cant use them as a web pages, so whats the point ? i mean, seriously, its subversion for Apache right?, is there any way to use a repository as a root of a web site ? so all changes committed to the repository can be viewed at the moment committed ? if so i couldent find the way to do that in the wabmin / virtualmin configurations if anyone knows how to do so i would be very happy if he / she could share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i mean, seriously, its subversion for Apache right?

Wrong. Subversion is a separate project which was [absorbed into the Apache Foundation](https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/subversion-joins-apache/) 6 years ago. The Apache Foundation has a wide range of projects under its umbrella, many of which have little to nothing to do with web servers.

> is there any way to use a repository as a root of a web site ?

Not directly. This is by design; you really do not want to do what you're describing, for a number of reasons including performance and security.

> so all changes committed to the repository can be viewed at the moment committed ?

The [Subversion FAQ](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#website-auto-update) describes how to keep your website updated with each commit.